# refreshing the contents of a listbox with .append() in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select

With jQuery on Firefox and Chrome I can just dynamically change the data in a listbox with `$().append()` statements or whichever way I need to. The same code doesn't work with IE. The listbox (`<select></select>`) is just static and none of the elements are added/removed/changed.

I heard IE can be a bit "different" in handling listbox (`<select></select>`) re-rendering.

How can you make jQuery's `.append()` work with Internet Explorer?

Comment: You mean `<select>` elements right?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/GYydZ/ this seems to work for me in ie8 and 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do. If you just want to load data using ajax and wanted to manipulate your `<select></select>`

```
var listBox = $("#CountyList");
$.post("/County/List/" + stateId, null, function (data) {
    var items = "<option value='0'>Select County</option>";
    $.each(data, function (i, c) {
        items += "<option value='" + c.Value + "'>" + c.Text + "</option>";
    });

    listBox.html(items);
}, 'json');
```

You then just need to form a string with all your `option` elements in it, then load it unto the `select` box using `.html()`

if you want a more elegant way to manipulate your `select` box . You could give this a try. http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/