# jQuery - Append items to listbox in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, listbox, append

Similar questions have been asked here and elsewhere (I had high hopes for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609353/refreshing-the-contents-of-a-listbox-with-append-in-internet-explorer)). But nothing I've found seems to apply directly to this problem.

I'm appending items to a listbox using jQuery. This code works perfectly in FF, Chrome, and Opera:

```
var newOpt = document.createElement("option");
newOpt.textContent = thisrowDistrict;
newOpt.value = thisrowDistrict;
lstDistricts.append(newOpt);
```

But this doesn't work in IE. According to a number of places I've looked, IE has issues with this, but I can't find any solution. Any idea how I can tweak this to run on all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes after: here is a way to work around the IE problem, using a different tool:

```
$('#lstDistricts').append("<option value='" + myDistrinct+ "'>" + myDistrinct+ "</option>");
```

I had one comment (he deleted it) that suggested that this worked for him:

```
var newOpt = document.createElement("option");
newOpt.textContent = thisrowDistrict;
newOpt.value = thisrowDistrict;
```

But I couldn't make it work on IE 11.

For what it's worth.